# How to get keycloak unathorized response in Json Format

Tags: java, json, keycloak

I'm doing keycloak authorization by using KeycloakOIDCFilter. If the authorization failed I'm getting below error.

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Unauthorized</body></html>
```

How I can get that error in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

I also could not find a configuration for that. Since Keycloak follows a web based work flow I guess you have to convert html on your side into JSON, if you don't want to go into source code of Keycloak.